# the first element im mysqli_query gives a 0

Tags: php

this is my code,

```
function update_profile($session_user_id, $email, $first_name, $last_name) {
    global $con;
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '$email' AND    `first_name` = '$first_name' AND `last_name` = '$last_name' WHERE `user_id` = $session_user_id");

}
```

When it updates it will change email to a 0.

Why is he doing that?

An edit...

for people who think its usefull.. this is my form.

```
if (isset($_POST['update_profile'])) {

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $error[] = 'Fill in a email';
} if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $error[] = 'Fill in a first name';
} else {
    if (email_exist($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != $user_data['email']) {
        $error[] = 'This email already exist.';
    } if (strlen($_POST['first_name']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['first_name']) > 30) {
        $error[] = 'This first name is to short or to long, it must be between a range of 3 and 30.';
    }
}

if (empty($error) == false) {
    echo error_handeling($error);
} else {
    $user_id = $session_user_id;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

    update_profile($session_user_id, $email, $first_name, $last_name);
}
}
?>

<h1><?php echo $user_data['first_name'] ?> his profile</h1>

<form action = "" method = "post">
<ul>
    <li>
        Email*:<br>
        <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php echo $user_data['email'] ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
        First name*:<br>
        <input type = "text" name = "first_name" value = "<?php echo $user_data['first_name'] ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type = "text" name = "last_name" value = "<?php echo $user_data['last_name'] ?>">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type = "submit" name = "update_profile" value = "Update">
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I have to put more text but idk what to put here. XD srry :)

Comment: What is the schema? What are you passing to the function? Why are you not using a parametrized query?

Comment: Please use prepared statements, or at least escape DB input yourself with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Try echoing the SQL to see what it's actually setting.

Comment: Check the syntax to use for an UPDATE statement, commas between the different column name/value pairs that you're setting rather than AND, otherwise the AND will be a logical operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using `AND` where you should just put a comma `,`

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '$email', `first_name` = '$first_name', `last_name` = '$last_name' WHERE `user_id` = $session_user_id");
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `AND` to `,` in your SQL:

```
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `users` 
                        SET `email` = '$email', 
                            `first_name` = '$first_name',
                            `last_name` = '$last_name' 
                        WHERE `user_id` = $session_user_id");
```

`AND` is a boolean operator. You're computing the value of the logical expression:

```
'$email' AND `first_name` = '$first_name' AND `last_name` = '$last_name'
```

If either of the name fields doesn't contain the value you're assigning, this returns `false`, which translates to `0`, and that's what you're storing.